# unset keyword gets underlined like there is an syntax error

Tags: php, aptana, unset, error-detection

I have this simple loop:

```
for($i=$_POST['position'];$i<count($myFiles);$i++)
{
    $withoutNumber = explode("_",$myFiles[$i]);
    $noNr = unset($withoutNumber[0]);
}
```

My code editor is Aptana, and the problem is that when I write this code I get the `unset` keyword underlined like is an syntax error and I have no idea why that happens. I can not test the code right now (this loop is part of a complex code) so I don't really know if the problem is real or not. What could the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You portion of code, if you try to execute it, gives :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_UNSET
```

Which means the problem is in your code, and not with your editor ;-)

Considering [`unset`](http://php.net/unset) doesn't return anything, you should have :

```
for($i=$_POST['position'];$i<count($myFiles);$i++)
{
    $withoutNumber = explode("_",$myFiles[$i]);
    unset($withoutNumber[0]);
}
```

Which is working much better : no Parse Error anymore.

And I suppose that Aptana "knows" that this language construct shouldn't return anything -- which is why it indicates there is an error.

Comment: that's absolutely right :D i admit that this is a stupid question :) i focused so much on that underlined unset that i forgot about that variable assignment :) thanks guys

Comment: You're welcome :-) (boah, not a problem ^^ at least you'll have learnt something ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

`unset` is a language construct and not a normal function, and thus can not be used to set a variable. See [unset()](https://www.php.net/unset):

> Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function ...

Comment: The note says that you can't do something like `$fn='unset'; $fn($v);`

Comment: I quoted this to underline the fact that it is not a regular function. I'll remove the misleading part.